# User role permissions per language

Tags: 8, users, i18n-l10n

Drupal 8 supports Multilingual (i18n) in core. I was wondering, is it possible to restrict users to be able to add/edit content for only one specific language?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [`hook_node_access`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/8.2.x) to control access to add/edit for the node.

For example, you can check the value of:

```
$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
```

and return the access result accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Working code example:

```
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;

/**
 * Implements hook_node_access().
 *
 * Prevent editor role to edit and/or delete fr/en nodes. Quick and dirty.
 */
function MYMODULE_node_access(NodeInterface $node, $op, AccountInterface $account) {

  $roles = $account->getRoles();

  $current_language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage();
  $lang             = $current_language->getId();

  if (!in_array('administrator', $roles) && !in_array('publisher', $roles)) {
    if ($op == 'update' || $op == 'delete') {
      if ($lang == 'en' || $lang == 'fr') {
        return AccessResult::forbidden();
      }
    }
  }

  // No opinion.
  return AccessResult::neutral();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Allowed Languages module makes it possible to set restrictions on which content a user can edit based on language.

https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_languages

Once installed against each user profile you can check which languages the user can edit as shown below.

[image: Allowed Languages]