# Deny access for Authenticated Users

Tags: 8, users

I'm using the moduke *[Permissions by Term](https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_by_term)* and I love it. It works great and my complete system is now build around it. But I ran into a certain case and I am wondering if this is even possible.

I want a node to be visible for Anonymous users but not for a logged in user with a certain role.

Is it possible to do this. Is it possible to hide content or deny access for a certain role to content that is available for Anonymous users?

Comment: You can deny access in a hook_node_access, like https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/257133/47547 without the language part.

Comment: For a module based option, try the content_access module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give a permission to the `Authenticated User` role, you grant that permission to all other logged-in roles. It works like this because all logged-in users get that role.

However, as long as you don't grant a permission specifically to the `Authenticated User` role, you can pick and choose which individual logged-in roles to give the permission to. Then you can also give the permission to the `Anonymous User` role.

Comment: That is why I proposed hook_node_access() to deny access, because this overrides all permissions granted through the Authenticated role and the Permission by Term module.

Comment: Very strange, because I tried this before I posted this question. I tried again this morning and...it works. Thanks!